# GD.SE Community Packaging Contest

Tags: discussion

A user asked: [Packaging design printing in small numbers?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70194/packaging-design-printing-in-small-numbers). And some of us advised that the user should create and assemble the package. joojaa commented saying that we should do a community competition and I thought this was a great idea.

So I am asking here to see if there is enough interest to get this started.

**Rules**

---

**Entry Period:**

1) 1 Week (starting on a Monday?), please comment on which date you think would be the best time to start the competition.

Or

2) It might not make too much sense to do a timed event and just do a submission date, say all submissions due between June 10-12th and start voting on that Monday.

**Prize:**

If we wanted to do a prize, we could post the submissions to the regular GD.SE and then award the winner with a bounty and up votes? I am willing to place the bounty. Otherwise we could follow the same suit as "Thursday Weekly Design Challenge" and post in Meta.

**Entry Requirements:**

- To keep things simple, I think we should make all packages using regular laser printer paper.
- Entry must be created and assembled by the user.
- Package size can be any size within reason. I do not think we need a size requirement but I would suggest the end package size to be between 2"x2"x2" and 24"x24"x24"
- The package design can be about anything that follows the requirements below. You have the freedom to create a package for any type of product, whether that is for a heart shaped chocolate box, juice container, a box with lid or a gift box.
- Entry cannot be sexually explicit or suggestive, violent or
  derogatory of any ethnic, racial, gender, religion, nationality,
  sexual orientation, professional or age group, profane or
  pornographic, contain nudity;
- Entry cannot be obscene or offensive, endorse any form of hate or hate group;
- Entry cannot defame, misrepresent or contain disparaging remarks about Sponsor or other people, products or companies;
- Entry may not include any intellectual property of third parties, including copyrighted material (including but not limited to music) or third-party trademarks
- Entry cannot depict, and cannot itself, be in violation of any law.

**How To Enter:**

Users will submit a photo of their assembled package and layout to GD.SE or Meta.GD.SE.

**Judging:**

If users want this to be a judging contest, then individual users can post their submission as an answer. Users can then up vote the submission they like. This can be done in either GD.SE or Meta.GD.SE. If we place a bounty, the user with the most votes will be awarded the bounty.

If we do not want to use up votes, then we can place the submissions in Meta and create a [Straw Poll](http://www.strawpoll.me/).

Comment: Whats the size? Whats the package containing?

Comment: @ryan I added information on size and package content in the entry requirements section.

Comment: Yes. Count me in!

Comment: Love the idea!  If this is happening, I'm in!

Comment: Oh. My... I did not saw this topic before!

Comment: I still plan on starting the co test soon. I have been busy working and moving. I am thinking we can start the contest later this month or early July.